# (Not a) Scala compiler bug? (null pointer exception)

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, nullpointerexception

This code

```
v(2,1)  
var m=Array[String]()
def v(f:Int,t:Int)=
{   var move= (10*f+t).toString

    m :+ "21"

}
```

(run it as a scala script)

gives a null pointer exception when executing the m:+ "21" line.

This

```
var m=Array[String]()
def v(f:Int,t:Int)=
{   var move= (10*f+t).toString

    m :+ "21"

}
v(2,1)
```

works. I think both should work and this is a compiler bug. Or am I mistaken?

Scala 2.8.1, Windows XP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mistaken: you are attempting to access the variable `m` before it has been initialized.

Note that just because the line with `m` on it is before the "problematic" line (i.e. where the exception is thrown) does not necessarily mean that it is run first.

I made this class (which exhibits the same behaviour when you create it):

```
class OrderTest {
  foo(1)
  val l = List("one", "two")
  def foo(i : Int) = println(l(i))
}
```

And then compiled with the *-print* option:

```
class OrderTest extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
  private[this] val l: List = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def l(): List = OrderTest.this.l;
  def foo(i: Int): Unit = scala.this.Predef.println(OrderTest.this.l().apply(i));
  def this(): test.OrderTest = {
    OrderTest.super.this();
    OrderTest.this.foo(1);
    OrderTest.this.l = immutable.this.List.apply(scala.this.Predef.wrapRefArray(Array[java.lang.String]{"one", "two"}.$asInstanceOf[Array[java.lang.Object]]()));
    ()
  }
}
```

You can see quite clearly what is going on

Comment: Facepalm :) you are quite correct. I'd assumed a two-pass compilation phase, and of course that's not how it works

Comment: Edited answer to give the full form of what the scala code is equivalent to

Comment: Paul: compilation is "two-phase" - otherwise the compiler couldn't see that v is used after being defined. Actually, even to compile Java you need many phases, so I'm not sure of what you have in mind.